# MySQL Stored Procedure Parameters are NULL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am stumped, and was hoping someone here would have a quick and easy answer.  I did a fresh install of MySQL 5.5 and am trying to pass parameters into a stored procedure.  The parameter values aren't being read by the stored procedure.  MySQL doesn't throw an error and processes the code with null parameters.  Here is the code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `testing`(IN parameter INTEGER)
BEGIN
    UPDATE table_name SET valueToChange = 'Test' WHERE mainID = @parameter;
END
```

And here is the query I'm using to call it:

```
USE database_name; CALL testing(72);
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I knew it was something basic... I removed the "@" symbol from the variable and everything works perfectly :)  Thanks to everyone that looked into this for me!